# Как открыть свою форму из property grid при попытке добавить элемент в список?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, propertygrid

Как в PropertyGrid при работе с полем типа List, на нажатие на кнопку "Добавить" открыть собственную форму?
т.е. у меня есть форма с объектом checkedListBox, который содержит некоторый список, я хочу в PropertyGrid при добавлении элемента в список открыть форму для выбора необходимых объектов из checkedListBoxа, а после закрытия этой формы, нужно чтобы выбранные элементы в checkedListBoxе добавились в список.

[image: Вот что я хочу получить]

Comment: Ваша хотелка вполне реализуема, но кода получается неприлично много для ответа на форуме. Смотрите [PropertyGrid FAQ](https://rsdn.org/article/dotnet/PropertyGridFAQ.xml). Имхо, ваш способ переусложнен. Я бы сделал [выпадающий список](https://rsdn.org/article/dotnet/PropertyGridFAQ.xml#EMIAE). Но если хочется непременно так, то вам дополнительно [сюда](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5372/How-to-Edit-and-Persist-Collections-with-Collectio).

Comment: В вашем способе морока в том, что нужно из стандартного редактора коллекций открывать дополнительную форму (а для этого как-то обработать клик по кнопке), а потом возвращать значения.

Answer (score 0):

Открыть свою форму при добавлении нового элемента в коллекцию можно переопределив метод [CollectionEditor.CreateInstance](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.collectioneditor.createinstance?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```cs
public MyCollectionEditor : CollectionEditor
{
    protected override object CreateInstance(Type itemType)
    {
        var item = new MyCollectionItem();
        using(var myForm = new MyForm(item))
        {
            // манипуляции с item
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

Получить доступ к создаваемой форме можно переопределив метод [CollectionEditor.CreateCollectionForm](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.collectioneditor.createcollectionform?view=netframework-4.7.2). Это может понадобится для добавления обработчиков события, локализации/настройки текста в форме и т.д.. Ниже пример того, как можно отобразить справку для выбранного свойства в обозревателе свойств (разумеется свойство должно быть декорировано атрибутами [Editor](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.editorattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) и [Description](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2)):

```cs
public MyCollectionEditor : CollectionEditor
{
    protected override CollectionForm CreateCollectionForm()
    {
        var form = base.CreateCollectionForm();
        form.Load += (sender, args) => onFormLoad(sender, args, form);
        return form;
    }

    private onFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs args, CollectionForm form)
    {
        var propertyBrowser = (PropertyGrid)getControlByName(form, "propertyBrowser");
        propertyBrowser.HelpVisible = true;
    }

    private Control getControlByName(Control control, string controlName)
    {
        if (control.Name == controlName)
        {
            return control;
        }

        foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
        {
            var findControl = getControlByName(childControl, controlName);
            if (findControl != null)
            {
                return findControl;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```